# Allowing users limited access only if they purchased successfully from stripe

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, jwt, stripe-payments

I am building a react site where users can purchase a "day", "weekly" or "monthly" pass for the content on the page. I only want to allow them access for a day if they purchase a day pass. Same for weekly and monthly. I am using JWT to keep users logged in. I have no idea how to create the functionality to verify if they should still have access or not. Would love some help. I am also using redux if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start thinking about [Authentication and Authorization](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/authz-and-authn) separately. Your JWTs are (hopefully) performing the Authentication duty. The "limited access" you're asking about are the concern of Authorization. In other words: now that you know who this user is, what are they allowed to do?

You need to map your JWTs to some form of internal user id, and then determine if they can or cannot access the requested resource/endpoint/etc.

For example, you might allow all users to GET from `/jobs` to view the listing of job postings, but if they try to `POST` to `/apply` for a job, you verify that they are a "premium" user, with time remaining on their paid subscription.